# In android, how to know if a notification is a new one or a repeated one?

Tags: android, notifications

In android, some apps post a notification when an event occurs (for example when your receive a message).

But until you dismiss this notification or open the app to see this event, the app will continue to post notifications about the same event.

In my app I only want to react once to  a specific event.

When the NotificationListenerService notify me of a notification how can i check if it's the first one or one of the following repeated ones ?

Thanks.

Comment: notifications use ids to define itself like notify(id, ...). and if you want to send only once it is a consideration inside your code that can be easiky implemented even wtih a flag. take a look at this to update a notification. http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Comment: i'm speaking about notifications from other apps

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the notification's specific details in local database after every notification that will notify.Then upon new notifications you need to check if that notification already exists in database if exists then don't notify it if it doesn't exits notify it and don't forget to store it to database after notifying. 
Hope this logic would help you. That's how i did it in my application.

Comment: i'm doing this for now but if the user receive two messages with the same content this won't work. i was looking for something like a unique id for each notifications.

Comment: You need to use some unique id. In my project i use time as unique id. Time that comes with notifications from server